# Does using ./ in relative links work with Windows servers?

Tags: html, iis, url, relative-path

Sorry if this is a stupid question...

I've developed an application that creates absolute links by prepending urls with the site root (of whichever site it is hosted).

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=SITE_ROOT?>/assets/css/global.css">
```

Notice that a slash is coming after site root. I need to convert this now to be relative links, so I tried using a dot as the value of SITE_ROOT.

This creates this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/global.css">
```

As far as I can tell, it works fine. Is this a legitimate relative link? Or is there a reason why I shouldn't do it this way?

**Note:** I'm not trying to go up a directory, otherwise I would use ../ I'm simply trying to stay in the same directory. Since there is a slash after SITE_ROOT, I can't leave it blank or it would become a root relative link.

**Update:** Will this work with IIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These links work on the client, not on the server, and as far as I know should behave the same as `<a>` links. `./assets/css/global.css` is the same as `assets/css/global.css`, meaning the folder assets under the current sub site. the `./` part is redundant.
If you what a link relative to the server you should start it with a slash, ie: `/assets/css/global.css` will go to `stackoverflow.com/assets/css/global.css`, even when you are on a sub site.

Comment: URLs are URLs, it works the same way as <a> elements, <img> elements, and any other element that takes a URL as a value to some attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's client side, so it should work with ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

its legitimate.

Just check if this works with IIS server. IMO it should. It does with Apache.

jrh

Comment: thanks for bringing up iis. forgot I need to make sure of that too.

Comment: Wasn't me, but could be because a question about links is purely an HTML question, regardless of the server. If anything, it should be checked cross-browser, not cross-server.